# Sort two different models on differently named fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sorting

I have two models: `PostType1`, `PostType1`.

```
class PostType1(models.Model):
    ...
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(_('created date'), blank=True, null=True)

class PostType2(models.Model):
    ...
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(_('publish date'), blank=True, null=True)
```

I make a query for both getting:

```
posts_type1 = PostType1.objects.all()
posts_type2 = PostType2.objects.all()
```

I know how to chain them:

```
posts = chain(posts_type1,posts_type2)
```

I'm looking for a way to sort them by date descending.
Is this possible ? Or shall I look to raw sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if your plan is to sort the union of the two querysets, you have to use the `sorted` method. I would go for something like:

```
sorted(chain(posts_type1, posts_type2), 
       key=lambda x: x.created_date if isinstance(x, PostType1) 
                                    else x.publish_date)
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same but my sorted arguments was a little bit clumsy not to say wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Each query can perform the sorting using `order_by`:

```
posts_type1 = PostType1.objects.all().order_by('-created_date')
posts_type2 = PostType2.objects.all().order_by('-publish_date')
```

If you want the whole result to be sorted, you could use a custom iterator instead of `chain`. An example for two models only (though not necessarily the cleanest one):

```
def chain_ordered(qs1, qs2):
    next1 = qs1.next()
    next2 = qs2.next()
    while next1 is not None or next2 is not None:
        if next1 is None: yield next2
        elif next2 is None: yeild next1
        elif next1 < next2:
            yield next1
            try:
                next1 = qs1.next()
            except StopIteration:
                next1 = None
        else:
            yield next2
            try:
                next2 = qs2.next()
            except StopIteration:
                next2 = None
```

StefanoP's suggestion of using `sorted` will work too, but AFAIK it will retrieve all items from database during the sorting, which may or may not be a concern to you.

Comment: The truth is that i want to loop back all my db . I'll prefer StefanoP's method because it is mre pythonic let's say. Thnak you for your post.

Comment: @geros sure, I prefer his solution too. Mine would only be useful if you were using cursors to retrieve your rows (for instance, if your whole data were too big to fit in memory).